# Better way to control spacing between block elements?

Tags: html, css

Is there a better way to control the space between certain block elements.. i basically have a few of these.

```
<div id="head1" class="global-box">
    <p>My Header Name</p>
    <select id="Select1">
         <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

problem is that the space between the My Header Name and the select html element is larger than i want... I tried removing the `<p>` but then its in line and select is on same line as the header title..

I could use `<br/>` but this just creates a block ?

Comment: Your first selector in your css file should be * { margin: 0px; padding 0px; } After that it becomes much easier to get the precise layout you want, such as adding a margin to one of the elements to position it. – blu 10 secs ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check into using a global reset style sheet (see [Resetting Again by Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/15/resetting-again/) or the YUI Reset)

This will remove all the margin assignments in all browsers to ensure consistency.

Then use this in your CSS style:

```
div.global-box p.header { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
```

Where 5px is the bottom margin (top right bottom left), so you can make it whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS

```
.global-box p {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.global-box select {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

You probably only need one of these, but it's difficult to know which.

Answer (score 0):

Try <select style='margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;'>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for just this `<p>`:

```
#head1 > p { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Otherwise, if you want to do this for all `class="global-box"` elements:

```
.global-box > p { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Note that if this doesn't give you enough room before the select, you can increase the margin-bottom amount.

Answer (score 0):

The visible space between elements is generally going to be either

- padding
- margin

So if you want less space, change your header line to

```
<p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">My Header Name</p>
```

and play with it.